# Можно ли сделать в iOS приложении ссылку на группу вк?

Tags: ios, appstore, мобильные-приложения

Разрешит ли Apple такую кнопку, которая отправляла бы пользователя в нашу группу вк посредством сафари? Типа как на сайтах: "Мы ВКонтакте и блаблабла..."

Comment: такесть же SDK

https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk

Comment: Не, меня как раз таки интересовало, разрешат они такое или нет, вдруг это каким-то их правилам противоречит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

коротко: Делать можно, они не запретят.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vk.com/"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

уже время ушло(( Apple считает ВК сайтом, который распространяет пиратский контент , и мне ДВА раза писал сапорт, чтобы я удалил ссылки с приложения на ВК!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ухты! а раньше работало ((